# Why is Zeke interested in Eren?

Tags: attack-on-titan

In *Attack on Titan*'s recent manga chapters, Zeke tells Eren that his father had lied to him and that he was unaware of the truth. Why is Zeke interested in Eren even when he can control titans and transform into one?

Comment: The last manga chapter might have given an explanation to your question,  but no details yet so I rather not spoil..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** This was further backed up by the events of chapter 87

What I think is that, according to latest manga chapter (86)

> Zeke and the other warriors are specifically trying to retake the coordinate from Grisha (and now Eren). He is also Eren's half brother (not step-brother) but it would appear that family is not an important bond to Zeke, as he betrayed both of his parents.

Comment: There must be reason behind betrayal, so I don't think we can get that sort of relationship off the table that easily.

Comment: @lentinant, except for the fact that he betrayed his parents as a young child. He has clearly been indoctrinated by the cause and is more dedicated to his mission than a family member he's never met before. The whole point of the Warriors mission is to get the Coordinate.

Comment: So, you think, he tries to receive Coordinate by deceiving Eren, that he has good intentions regarding him? After all, what have happened already?

Comment: Um, no. I think Zeke just wants the Coordinate from Eren and wants to either kill him or have him join him. I don't think Zeke feels any loyalty towards Eren nor does he have good intentions for him. Zeke's goal is to take the Coordinate back and kill the people inside the Walls.

Comment: I mean, why do you think Zeke said Eren, that he will save him? What he expects to achieve with that?

Comment: Given that a few pages before that Zeke says that Eren has been brainwashed it's clear that Zeke thinks what he is fighting for is right and what Grisha was fighting for was wrong. I think that this is just Zeke trying to indoctrinate Eren or at least attempt to lure him away so that he can take the Coordinate from him.

Comment: But according to the same chapter titans are becoming obsolete and maybe the humans not living inside the wall have weapons that are more advanced than those used by survey corps to fight the titans, so how would zeke benefit from capturing eren ? I mean marleyans can just use their advanced weapons to kill the titans and since they are becoming obsolete marleyans would not want to waste time in finding the coordinate

Comment: Zeke wants to kill those in the wall: "When Ymir and Eren are kidnapped by Reiner Braun and Bertolt Hoover, Ymir states that the Beast Titan is directly responsible for the appearance of Titans within Wall Rose; possibly in order to "test" humanity's strength. She also notes that the reaction of Reiner and Bertolt to his appearance resembled gawking, excited children." And the Marleyans' goal is to take the coordinate as stated on page 43 of the most recent chapter ("retake the power of the original Titan").

Answer (score 0):

According to latest manga chapter, 86,

> Zeke is older step-brother to Eren. He was child of Grisha from previous wife, in "outer world". Full motives of Zeke are still unknown, but, most probably, he fills empathy to Eren, thinking that his brother was also used as tool by Grisha in his quest for revenge.

Comment: Either that or he want Eren's coordinates. Can't really think of another reason...

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler alert. In the story, it is said that Zeke ...

> ... was brainwashed by Marleyan government when his parents, Grisha dan Dina Yeager, sent him to be a spy by joining the training to be a warrior. Zeke ended up believing what their father told him was untrue and ended up betraying them.

So I think he told something like that to Eren because ...

> ... he believed what the Marleyan told him was true and he wanted to tell Eren that everything he knew from their father was wrong. Perhaps he wanted Eren, the current holder of The Founding Titan and The Attack Titan to be Marleyan allies. That's their goal that we know so far.

But ...

> Since the story hasn't ended yet, another possibilities might happen later. Zeke is surely full of secrets.

Zeke still wanted Eren even he can control and transform titan perhaps because ...

> ... the power of the founding titan or what they called as the coordinate is considered thousand times more powerful when it comes to control people.

Remember back then when Zeke ...

> ... confronted Mike in Wall Rose? The titan still crushed Mike even Zeke told it not to. His titan's controlling power was so much weaker compared to the founding titan when the first king managed to command millions of colossal titan to make the wall and modified the memories of people those living inside it.

And I guess Zeke's power of controlling titans ...

> ... has something to do with the royal blood that flowing inside him, since it's said that the previous holder of beast titan didn't have that kind of ability.

Answer (score 0):

> Zeke Yeager is Erens half brother. His parents are Grisha Yeager and
>  one of the kings royal blood predecessors(who later becomes the smiley
>  titan that kills Erens mother and Hannes). He betrayed his parents and
>  got them caught.

To understand why:

> Basically, there's an island where the humans are thriving outside the
>  three walls. these are the original people. the people protected by
>  the three walls (Eldians) are meant to have betrayed humanity, so they
>  were cast away. The ones that remained on the main island were treated
>  like they were dogs. After the military in the main island killed
>  Grishas sister by feeding her to the dogs, Grisha swore to kill all
>  the Marley (people on the main island that discriminate the Eldians).
>  They finally realised that they need the coordinates from the king
>  (Whos behind the wall). The Marley want the coordinates too, so they
>  assemble Eldian soldiers to go and get the coordinates. The soldiers
>  will be given the power of the eight titans the Marley government had.
>  Grisha planned to use his son Zeke to get into the army, become a
>  titan, and then steal the power of the king for the Eldians, but he
>  rats them out.

In conclusion:

> Zeke Yeager, Reiner, Annie, and Bertholdt use their titan powers to
>  try to get the coordinates from Eren. He doesn't want to eat Eren, he
>  wants Eren to realise that the Marley government is the true
>  Government and that both he and Zeke were used by their parents.

and that is why Grisha is obsessed with Eren

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Answer (score 0):

An update with the latest information from the recent chapters.

It was revealed in **Chapter 114** that

> Zeke's true plan was Eldia's euthanization. He believed that it was the only salvation for the Eldians. He also believed that without Eldians, there would be no more suffering in the world.

Thus, he sought Eren in order

> **to convince Eren to take part in his plan of euthanasia of the entire Eldian race**. He also tried convincing Eren that it was the only path to 'salvation'. Marley's orders to recover the Coordinate was a perfect cover for his true intentions as none would suspect why he's interested in Eren, the current wielder of the Coordinate.

He must have

> succeeded because as seen in the recent chapters, Eren is now in league with Zeke after they talked during Eren's infiltration to Marley. Personally, I still have doubts on whether this is all a ruse or something. Titan-shifters can see memories of the future and it's possible Eren might have seen or known something via these memories that made him side with Zeke.